# Extracting value from nested hashes and arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, nested

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
h = { 
  a: [ ["c", "1"],["d","2"],["e","3"],["f","4"] ], 
  b: [ ["g","5"],["h","6"],["i","7"],["j","8"] ], 
  c: [ ["k","9"],["l","10"],["m","11"],["n","12"] ]
}
```

What is the best way to extract the numbers from it so it looks like this?

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

I tried a few different things but it always required an external array that I have to push into from a chain of `each` commands.

Comment: For fun, `h.to_s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).sort`.

Comment: It's helpful to assign example inputs to variables (e.g., `h = { a:...}`), so that readers can reference those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short alternative way using `Array#transpose` method:

```
> h.values.flatten(1).transpose.last
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]

# with to number conversion
> h.values.flatten(1).transpose.last.map(&:to_i)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

**Benchmarks**

```
require 'benchmark'

h = {
  a: [ ["c", "1"],["d","2"],["e","3"],["f","4"] ],  
  b: [ ["g","5"],["h","6"],["i","7"],["j","8"] ], 
  c: [ ["k","9"],["l","10"],["m","11"],["n","12"] ] 
}   

Benchmark.bm(10) do |x|
  x.report("transpose") do
    1000.times { h.values.flatten(1).transpose.last.map(&:to_i) }
  end
  x.report("collect/map") do
    1000.times { h.values.flatten(1).collect(&:last).map(&:to_i) }
  end
  x.report("regexp") do
    1000.times { h.values.flatten.select { |v| v.match(/\d/) }.map(&:to_i) }
  end
  x.report("Integer") do
    1000.times { h.values.flat_map { |a| a.map { |_,e| Integer(e) } } }
  end
end
```

**Results**

```
                 user     system      total        real
transpose    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.006971)
collect/map  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.007490)
regexp       0.030000   0.010000   0.040000 (  0.031939)
Integer      0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.006832)
```

Comment: I love this solution! All of them are great but this one is the cleanest one!

Comment: Your results seem to hold up with greater numbers of keys and larger value arrays. I tried it with `n = m = 50` where `f = :a; h = { a: hh[:a]*n }; m.times { h[f = f.next] = h[:a] }`, where `hh` is your hash `h`.

Answer (score 6):

I would do:

```
h.values.flatten(1).map{|x,y| y.to_i }
```

Comment: Good one, hirolau. As I did, it's best to assume that the first element of each pair could contain a digit.

Comment: `map(&:last).map(&:to_i)` is a little longer, but more readable to me. Also based on the question I see no reason to assume you would ever want to get the first value of a pair, so this answer gets my vote.

Comment: Yes, I just do not like putting two maps after each other for some reason. Maybe `.map{|x| x.last.to_i }`.

Comment: Great solution. Transpose one is just cleaner:) Ty.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with regular expressions.

```
hash.values.flatten.select { |v| v.match(/\d/) }.map(&:to_i)
```

- To get the values, use the `values` method
- To make the array one-dimensional, use the `flatten` method.
- To filter, use the `select` method, and find the strings that match a regular-expression for a number.
- Finally, map this array to convert the elements to integers.

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of `flatten`, `select` and `regexp` for digit `\d`:

```
=> a = { 
  a: [ ["c", "1"],["d","2"],["e","3"],["f","4"] ], 
  b: [ ["g","5"],["h","6"],["i","7"],["j","8"] ], 
  c: [ ["k","9"],["l","10"],["m","11"],["n","12"] ]
}
=> a.values.flatten.select { |x| x =~ /\d/ }.map(&:to_i)
#> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Other way `flat_map`, `map` and `( )`:

<sup>[reach inside the structure with parentheses to make things more explicit](http://po-ru.com/diary/rubys-magic-underscore/)</sup>

```
=> a = { 
  a: [ ["c", "1"],["d","2"],["e","3"],["f","4"] ], 
  b: [ ["g","5"],["h","6"],["i","7"],["j","8"] ], 
  c: [ ["k","9"],["l","10"],["m","11"],["n","12"] ]
}
=> a.flat_map { |_, (n, z, i, x)| [n, z, i, x] }.map { |_, i| i.to_i }
#> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Consider replacing `x =~ /\d/` with `Integer(x) rescue nil`. That permits the first element of a pair to be "c8" or "8c" (but not `"8"`). Your second solution is unnecessarily restrictive, requiring that one knows the first value of every pair in advance.

Comment: i prefer to avoid things like `raise` and `rescue` because it very slow, second solution for _robots only :)_, also rescue all it's very buggy, it can `rescue` something very important than `x`, for example (code with typo) `Intger(x) rescue nil => nil`

Comment: Then perhaps `x =~ /^-?\d+$/`.

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
def pull_numbers(h)
  h.values.flat_map { |a| a.map { |_,e| Integer(e) } }
end
```

**Example**

Your hash, with `h[:a][0][0]` modified slightly:

```
h = { 
  a: [["8c", "1"],["d","2"],["e","3"],["f","4"]], 
  b: [["g","5"],["h","6"],["i","7"],["j","8"]], 
  c: [["k","9"],["l","10"],["m","11"],["n","12"]]
}

pull_numbers(h)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

**Explanation**

The steps, for the example above:

```
c = h.values
  #=> [[["8c", "1"], ["d", "2"], ["e", "3"], ["f", "4"]],
  #    [["g", "5"], ["h", "6"], ["i", "7"], ["j", "8"]],
  #    [["k", "9"], ["l", "10"], ["m", "11"], ["n", "12"]]]
```

[Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) passes the first element of `c` and sets the block variable `a`:

```
a = [["8c", "1"],["d","2"],["e","3"],["f","4"]]
```

Then:

```
a.map { |_,e| Integer(e) }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I chose to use `Integer(e)` rather than `e.to_i` so that an exception is raised if `e` is not the string representation of an integer :

```
Integer("cat")
  #=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "cat"
```

whereas:

```
"cat".to_i
   #=> 0
```

In effect, `Integer` performs a data check before making the conversion.

The other two elements of `c` are processed similarly.

**Variant**

One could instead write:

```
def pull_numbers(h)
  h.values.flatten.each_slice(2).map { |_,e| Integer(e) }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
h = { 
  a: [ ["c", "1"],["d","2"],["e","3"],["f","4"] ], 
  b: [ ["g","5"],["h","6"],["i","7"],["j","8"] ], 
  c: [ ["k","9"],["l","10"],["m","11"],["n","12"] ]
}

h.values.flatten(1).collect(&:last).map(&:to_i)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Or you can do this:

```
h.to_a.flatten.select { |x| x =~ /\d/ }.map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: From the standpoints of both efficiency and readability, isn't `h.values` superior to `h.to_a`?

Comment: Yes, it should be. I was just trying variety of ways to get this done